# Heroku Django translations

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am using `rosetta` in my Django app. I have set all the translation strings and it is working with my local environment. The problem is when I push the code to heroku, I get the error: `CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.` when running the code `heroku run python manage.py makemessages -l en`

**EDIT**

Following the suggestions of @nik_m I am adding the post_compile script but I am getting the error:

```
In post-compile hook        
remote: -----> Compiling translation files        
remote:        CommandError: Can't find msgfmt. 
Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

Comment: Is `django-rosetta` in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: yes I currently have django-rosetta==0.7.12

Comment: There is no reason to run `makemessages` on heroku. You should just `git push heroku master` and that's it.

Comment: For some reason the website is not changing language in heroku

Comment: So, this is ought to another reason. Maybe due to `django-rosetta`. I have never used it so I can't tell. I always use Django's built-in translation and never had any problems.

Comment: After some search I concluded to [this](https://wearespindle.com/articles/how-to-heroku-automatic-translations). Might help you!

Comment: I am getting some error when pushing to heroku.

Comment: Have you installed the [heroku-buildpack-gettext](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/lexifdev/heroku-buildpack-gettext) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137954/discussion-between-rgfvfk-iff-and-nik-m).

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely already checked this, but is the requirements.txt file up to date with the pip installations?

pip freeze > requirements.txt

git add .

git commit -m "new req.txt"

git push heroku master

i hope this helped out!
-Cheers

Answer (score 0):

While it is not the same question, my answer for another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67096332/3768552) might help you as well.

[Since Heroku 20](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/198#issuecomment-185169313), `gettext` is automatically added for the default Python build package. This is only during build and not at runtime. Therefore the command should be executed just after build. Since `gettext` is automatically added you shouldn't get the error anymore.

As @nik_m already mentioned, this can be done using the post compile file in `bin/post_compile` (no extension like procfile) with the following line:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

Optionally you can add the specific language (e.g. `python manage.py compilemessages -l nl`)

Since Heroku automatically adds gettext, there is no more need to add additional build packs (at least for `gettext`) like the one mentioned in the comments.

You shouldn't run the `makemessages` command in your Heroku environment. This can be done locally and those files can be committed to the repository (assuming you fill in the right translations here).