# Django+Heroku: compilemessages works but not MY translation file.

Tags: python, django, heroku

I find myself in a very weird situation:

1. I do not have my `.mo` files committed into my repo. I plan to generate them after I deploy
2. I installed the gettext buildpack availabe at `https://github.com/piotras/heroku-buildpack-gettext.git`

So this are the steps I did:

1. Deploy to heroku.
2. Run `heroku run python manage,py compilemessages`
3. This is being outputted:

   processing file django.po in /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/redirects/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES

   processing file django.po in /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/redirects/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES

   processing file django.po in /app/prometheus/locale/zh_hans/LC_MESSAGES

   processing file django.po in /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES
4. List one of files: `heroku run ls /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/redirects/locale/zh_Hans/LC_MESSAGES` RESULTS: `django.mo  django.po`
5. List our file: `heroku run ls /app/prometheus/locale/zh_hans/LC_MESSAGES/`
   RESULTS: `django.po`

#### django.mo is missing.

I ran `python manage.py shell` to see if I have some variables wrong:

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
In [1]: from django from django.conf import settings
In [3]: print(settings.BASE_DIR)
/app/prometheus
In [4]: print(settings.LOCALE_PATHS)
('/app/prometheus/locale',)
```

So i have no idea why my django.mo file is not being generated.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 4):

[Since Heroku 20](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/198#issuecomment-185169313), gettext is automatically added for the default Python build package. This is only during build and not at runtime. Therefore the command should be executed just after build.

Luckily this can be done using the post compile file in `bin/post_compile` (no extension like procfile) with the following line:

```
python manage.py compilemessages
```

Optionally you can add the specific language (e.g. `python manage.py compilemessages -l nl`)

Since Heroku automatically adds gettext, there is no more need to add additional build packs (at least for `gettext`) like the one from Piotras mentioned above.

These files are generated in the build phase and will be part of the compressed image. Therefore they should not be deleted afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Django.mo is generated and then deleted.

I'm in the same situation and tried to generate the files with

```
$ heroku run django-admin compilemessages
$ heroku run ls locale/LANG/LC_MESSAGES/
django.po
```

I didn't want to wait for connecting to Heroku on every command and used

```
$ heroku run "django-admin compilemessages; ls locale/LANG/LC_MESSAGES/"
django.mo django.po
$ heroku run ls locale/LANG/LC_MESSAGES/
django.po
```

Turns out, django.mo is created but for some reason it is immediately deleted.

Googling this gives Heroku Help -page [Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted):

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy.

What happens is

```
heroku run COMMAND
```

starts a new dyno, runs the command in it and shuts down the dyno once the command has exited, so all the files the command created are deleted.

As far as I know, options are either to commit the .mo-files to repo or serve them from storage, [for example S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).

Comment: Yeah, I started to commit the `.mo` to solve the issue. To me it looks like a minor sin.

Comment: Heroku's ephemeral filesystem always gets me and causes a few hours of madness. I hope this is the last time I get bitten by it haha. Thank you!